# regex specific string out of URL with paramenters

Tags: javascript, regex

Please realize the string "unser-leitbild.html" inside the parametersection of the below URL.

```
/folderone/foldertwo/filename.php?parameter=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.igmetall-sprockhoevel.de%2Fueber-uns%2Funser-leitbild.html&utf8=0&dir=sprockhoevel&updateJquery=jquery-1.6.2.min.js
```

This is my requirement: 
I am looking to create a variable giving me the FILENAME  from FILENAME.html. The special issue here is that this needs to be obtained from within the  parametersection of the URL.  the FILENAME will always have the ending '.html'

Okay: So my aim is to receive the string "unser-leitbild" out of the above URL.
We want to be using javascript and/or regex.

I gained the above mentioned URL like this:

```
var URL = (location.pathname+location.search).substr(1); 
var filename = URL;
alert(filename);
```

But How can I extract the STRING "unser-leitbild"  and obtain that String  as a variable ?

Be careful: The actual filename will always be filename.php. But the filename.php is irrelevant here!!

HINT ONE: We always need to search for the  filename.HTML. Which can be found inside the parameter-section only.

HINT TWO:  inside the parameter-section we will ALWAYS find a filename '.html'. The html-ending will always ocurr only once.

We want to find the Filename "INSIDE THE PARAMETER-SECTION"  and extract the name of the html-file without its ending. In our example that would be:  "unser-leitbild"

RESULT = 'unser-leitbild'

To get you started, here are my unsuccessful attempts     http://pastebin.com/Mt2ZTUUb

Comment: http://jsbin.com/mujopij/edit?js,output

Comment: Once I have gained the Value, I aim to add that value as a Class-name to the Body-tag using JQuery.  But I was running into regex issues. It is a bit harder to gain the Value, as the filename we want to extract resides inisde the parametersection of the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
\?parameter.*(?:\/|%2F)([^.]*).html
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/RFoNh5/2)

```js
const regex = /\?parameter.*(?:\/|%2F)([^.]*).html/g;
const str = `/folderone/foldertwo/filename.php?parameter=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.igmetall-sprockhoevel.de%2Fueber-uns%2Funser-leitbild.html&utf8=0&dir=sprockhoevel&updateJquery=jquery-1.6.2.min.js`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Comment: Hey Maverick, I am greateful for your extraordinay solution. I wanted to answer inside a comment directly. But I remained unable to edit my code-section inside the stackoverflow-comment-textfield. Probably due to my missing markdown experience :) I had to create a separate answer. Please find my separate answer below. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am greateful for your extraordinay reply.

Here is some feedback: I tested your solution and found out it worked very stable. I merely ran into one error, which happend on the startpage, see below for details. All through my 43 pages: the solution works like a charm!  I ajusted the code a little bit until the code-snippet applied for my production-environment:

```
     const regex = /\?url.*(?:\/|%2F)([^.]*).html/g;    

   var str = (location.pathname+location.search).substr(1);    

  let m;

  while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
      if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
          regex.lastIndex++;
      }
  console.log(m[1]);
  }
```

The only unexpected issue ocurred on the startpage, as the startpage has no filename ;) The Startpage only has domain.com but no /index.html.  regex was unable to find a filename, simply because there was none. I was able to easily solve that little problem: I used JQuery to create an exeption for the startpage and was fine on all pages.  I am truely greateful. I received only one answer, but that answer was totally on the spot! Maverick really took the time to digg deep into my question until he fully understood my problem at hand. And Maverick solved the issue on his very first answer. Extremely precize answer, I am impressed & greateful. Problem solved!